# Jquery set width, wait for update

Tags: jquery

I am trying to have a small bit of jquery set the size of a select element at page load, then set the size of it's container based on the new auto size.  This works sometimes, but seems to fail with a slower page load.  If I debug the code and pause at each line it works 100% of the time, so I assume each action is not completing before the next line fires.  I tried adding setTimeout for each line, which helped a small bit, but not all the time.  Any way to fix this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  //set select element to auto width
  setTimeout(function(){$("#PunchDD").width("auto");},5); 

  //Add some width to the element to account for custom drop down arrow
  setTimeout(function(){$("#PunchDD").width($("#PunchDD").width() + 17);},5);

  //Set container width a bit smaller to hide the stock drop down arrow
  setTimeout(function(){$("#PunchDDContainer").width($("#PunchDD").width() - 18);},5);
});
```

Also I don't want to set the size to auto in css as I use fixed sizes there for failback when javascript is not working.

Comment: Can you wait for the `load` event instead of `ready`?  The difference is that `load` waits for all static resources (which can have an effect on the page layout), where as `ready` simply waits for the DOM to be ready for manipulation.

Comment: A select element ***IS*** ready when the DOM is loaded, it does'nt need to wait for static resources like images.

Comment: @adeneo Correct, but his problem is *layout* related, which may *not* be stable until the `load` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your event to work on window load instead of document ready:

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
    // fun shtuffs
});
```

This should solve the issue because the window and CSS formatting has already loaded before any manipulation takes place.